# Switching two mainwindows

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots, qt-signals

I am new to QT GUI programming. 
I am trying to test switching two mainwindows continously by using show and hide.

I have created a simple code in main.cpp

```
      main(){
      QApplication a(argc , argv)
      Mainwinodw1 *window1 = new Mainwindow1();
      Mainwinodw1 *window2 = new Mainwindow2();

      for (;;)

        {
           window1->show();
           delay();
           window1->hide();

           window2->show();
           delay();
           window2->hide();

        }

      return a.exec();

      }
```

The test can display the windows only one time , but duirng the second iteration they dont show and hide.

Can somebody help to fix this.

Comment: MainWindow1 is a class. window1 is pointer. window1.show is a typo. it is window1->show();

Comment: The main problem is                                                                  
           winodw1. show cannot display for the second iteration

Comment: Yes the parent widget = NULL .

Comment: basically these are two mainwindow forms , after show() can the hide() be called directly or is it necessary to save the window context and resume some thing like that!!

Comment: There are not mouse events to handle, the windows should switch only by the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Qt timers instead of hardcoded delay function.

main.cpp file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Mainwindow1 *window1 = new Mainwindow1();
    Mainwindow2 *window2 = new Mainwindow2();
    WindowSwitcher ws(window1, window2, 2000);

    window1->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

`WindowSwitcher` source code:

```
#include "windowswitcher.h"
#include <QTimer>

WindowSwitcher::WindowSwitcher(QMainWindow *w1, QMainWindow *w2, int delay) : QObject(), window1(w1), window2(w2)
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(switchWindow()));
    timer->start(delay);
}

void WindowSwitcher::switchWindow()
{
    if (window1->isVisible())
    {
        window1->hide();
        window2->show();
    }
    else
    {
        window1->show();
        window2->hide();
    }
}
```

WindowSwitcher header file:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMainWindow>

class WindowSwitcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WindowSwitcher(QMainWindow *w1, QMainWindow *w2, int delay);

private:
    QMainWindow *window1;
    QMainWindow *window2;

public slots:
    void switchWindow();
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. I understood the problem is with the timer.

Comment: I am using QT4.8.7 on arm cortex A9 cpu (800Mhz) on linux platform.

Time for each frame : 30-40 milli seconds. Frame size: 640x480 pixels.
I see the window rendering is very slow on the screen. @ramzes2